# How "to ensure proper integration between HttpRepl and Visual Studio Code."?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use httprepl to test endpoints in my ASP.NET app. When I tried to run a POST request my Command Prompt returned:

```
The default editor must be configured using the command `pref set editor.command.default "{commandLine}"`.
```

So I set it with the following command:

```
pref set editor.command.default "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"
```

Then I get a warning:

```
If your default editor is Visual Studio Code, you should set the default command arguments (`editor.command.default.arguments`) to include `-w` or `--wait` to ensure proper integration between HttpRepl and Visual Studio Code.
```

I don't know what to do at this point. I tried:

```
pref set editor.command.default.arguments "-w"
```

I'm not sure whether that worked or not, but when I try to repeat the command to set VS Code as my default editor, I get the same warning. Have I got that right?

Answer (score 2):

This answer is based on a **nodejs** via **httprepl** setup

I think you might have already figured it out. However, since I got the same error (using nodejs and httprepl instead), I just post my answer for others' reference. For me, it had nothing to do with the "default editor", I only need to add `-c "{}"` after `post`.

```
post -c "{}" -h Content-Type=application/json
```

the -c provides an (empty in this case) inline HTTP request body. you may also provide some other stuff like: `-c "{"id":2,"name":"Cherry"}"` according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/http-repl/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows#test-http-post-requests)

For the backend I use nodejs and express, and noted that I have to add `express.json()` for it to work

```
const Router = express.Router();
Router.use(express.json())

Router.post('/some/path/',async (request: Request, response: Response) => {
    console.log(reuqest.body)
    response.send('ok')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

[Test web APIs with the HttpRepl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/http-repl/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=macos#test-http-options-requests)

Set vscode to your default editor that command is:

```
pref set editor.command.default "/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code"
```

then you should set the editor.command.default.arguments key like this:

```
pref set editor.command.default.arguments "--disable-extensions --new-window"
```

additional, you should add "--wait" or "-w" to the argument like this:

```
pref set editor.command.default.arguments "--disable-extensions --new-window --wait"
```

use this command to brower what preferences you have setted:

```
pref get
```

finally don't forget restart you vscode!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you've got that right. I did the same (with "--wait" instead of "-w") and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in an Ubuntu environment, try this one:

```
pref set editor.command.default /usr/bin/gedit
```

It worked for me pretty well.